# How to differentiate between WVGA800 (480x800) WVGA854 (480x854) hdpi (240dpi)

Tags: android

I have two devices WVGA800(htc desire) & WVGA854(emulator) 240hdpi . 
I need to scale image differently on each device but each time it takes the same layout.

My folder layout is as under:

```
layout-normal-long-hdpi
layout-normal-notlong-hdpi
```

but both takes the layout from normal-long , 
dont understand why is that, I even tried *normal-long-land-hdpi* but didnt worked.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008499/how-to-differentiate-the-480x800-and-480x854-screens-in-android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im pretty sure the fall into the same category. you may want to actually get screen pixel height and act accordingly.

http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Answer (score 0):

See [how to differentiate the 480X800 and 480X854 screens in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3008499/how-to-differentiate-the-480x800-and-480x854-screens-in-android)