# Android: Native App Background resolution? 480x800? or 480x774?

Tags: android, background, resolution

I am targeting devices that have native resolution of 480x800; however, my background image (480x800) gets resized (shrink down) to 480x774 because of the title bar on top. I know that Dell Streak or Samsung Galaxy Tab will have shorter (in terms of resolution) title bar since the screen size is bigger (although the resolution is same: 480x800)

Is there a way to make background stretch from all the way from top (including title bar) to very bottom? I don't care some top part of image is covered by Android title bar.

I just don't want 480x800 background image to shrink down.

I already use fill parent:

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/background"
```

Comment: Doesn't the "native resolution" depend on the device?

Comment: For what it's worth, the Galaxy Tab actually does have a higher resolution (1024x600, I believe).

Comment: Close duplicate of [What resolution should my Android splash screens be?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2561598/what-resolution-should-my-android-splash-screens-be)