# android splash screen sizes for ldpi,mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi displays ? - eg : 1024X768 pixels for ldpi

Tags: android, splash-screen, pixel-density

I have to design splash screens(images that fit screen while loading) for android application using phonegap. I have to design 4 size images that fit for 4types of screens like ldpi, mdpi , hdpi, xhdpi . Can anyone tell me exact sizes in pixels for these screens so I can design in that size ?

Example answer :

```
ldpi - 1024X768 px
mdpi  - 111 X 156 px  

 We support ldpi, mdpi, hdpi and xhdpi displays; the following will define splash screens for each specific screen type.

<gap:splash src="splash/android/ldpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="ldpi" />
<gap:splash src="splash/android/mdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="mdpi" />
<gap:splash src="splash/android/hdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="hdpi" />
<gap:splash src="splash/android/xhdpi.png" gap:platform="android" gap:density="xhdpi" />
```

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12242111/application-skeleton-to-support-multiple-screen) will help you

Answer (score 102, accepted):

There can be any number of different screen sizes due to Android having no set standard size so as a guide you can use the minimum screen sizes, which are provided by Google.

According to Google's statistics the majority of ldpi displays are small screens and the majority of mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi and xxhdpi displays are normal sized screens.

- xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

You can view the statistics on the relative sizes of devices on Google's dashboard which is [available here](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Screens).

More information on multiple screens can be found [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html).

### 9 Patch image

The best solution is to create a nine-patch image so that the image's border can stretch to fit the size of the screen without affecting the static area of the image.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch

Comment: Could you also include xxhdpi? (if it exists)

Comment: Google define xxhdpi as ~480 DPI. They don't provide a minimum screen size for this from what I can see.

Comment: Why does this have so many upvotes? `xlarge != xhdpi`, they're measuring two totally different things. Those dp sizes are listed for the size buckets, not density.

Comment: @geobits look at the question. He is asking what size his splash screens should be for each density that he supports. As there can be any number of different sizes due to Android having no set standard size the closest correct answer we can give is the minimum screen sizes, which is provided by Google. You can read more about this if you follow the link in the answer.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but that isn't what your answer says. If it did, I wouldn't have even commented. He asked for a size list, and you simply give a list based on something else with no explanation. You should edit it in, whether or not you link to the docs.

Answer (score 165):

### Splash screen sizes for Android

**and at the same time for Cordova (a.k.a Phonegap), React-Native and all other development platforms**

```
Format : 9-Patch PNG (recommended)

Dimensions

 - LDPI:
    - Portrait: 200x320px
    - Landscape: 320x200px
 - MDPI:
    - Portrait: 320x480px
    - Landscape: 480x320px
 - HDPI:
    - Portrait: 480x800px
    - Landscape: 800x480px
 - XHDPI:
    - Portrait: 720px1280px
    - Landscape: 1280x720px
 - XXHDPI
    - Portrait: 960x1600px
    - Landscape: 1600x960px
 - XXXHDPI 
    - Portrait: 1280x1920px
    - Landscape: 1920x1280px
```

**Note:** Preparing XXXHDPI is not needed and also maybe XXHDPI size too because of the repeating areas of 9-patch images. On the other hand, if only Portrait sizes are used the App size could be more less. More pictures mean more space is need.

### Pay attention

I think there is no an exact size for the all devices. I use Xperia Z 5". If you develop a crossplatform-webview app you should consider a lot of things (whether screen has softkey navigation buttons or not, etc). Therefore, I think there is only one suitable solution. The solution is [to prepare a **9-patch splash screen**](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) (find `How to design a new splash screen` heading below).

1. Create splash screens for the above screen sizes as **9-patch**. Give names your files with **.9.png** suffixes
2. Add the lines below into your config.xml file
3. Add the splash screen plugin if it's needed.
4. Run your project.

That's it!

**Cordova specific code 
 To be added lines into the config.xml for 9-patch splash screens**

```
<preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
<preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="6000" />
<platform name="android">
    <splash src="res/screen/android/ldpi.9.png" density="ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/mdpi.9.png" density="mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/hdpi.9.png" density="hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/xhdpi.9.png" density="xhdpi"/> 
</platform>
```

To be added lines into the config.xml when using **non**-9-patch splash screens

```
<platform name="android">
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-hdpi.png" density="land-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-ldpi.png" density="land-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-mdpi.png" density="land-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-land-xhdpi.png" density="land-xhdpi"/>

    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-hdpi.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-ldpi.png" density="port-ldpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-mdpi.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/splash-port-xhdpi.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
</platform>
```

### How to design a new splash screen

I would describe a simple way to create proper splash screen using this way. Assume we're designing a 1280dp x 720dp - xhdpi (x-large) screen. I've written for the sake of example the below;

- In Photoshop:  File -> New  in new dialog window set your screens

  Width: 720  Pixels
  Height: 1280 Pixels

  I guess the above sizes mean Resolution is 320 Pixels/Inch. But to ensure you can change resolution value to 320 in your dialog window. In this case **Pixels/Inch = DPI**

  Congratulations... You have a 720dp x 1280dp splash screen template.

### How to generate a 9-patch splash screen

After you designed your splash screen, if you want to design 9-Patch splash screen, you should insert 1 pixel gap for every side. For this reason you should increase +2 pixel your canvas size's width and height ( now your image sizes are 722 x 1282 ).  
I've left the blank 1 pixel gap at every side as directed the below.
 
Changing the canvas size by using Photoshop: 
- Open a splash screen png file in Photoshop 
- Click onto the lock icon next to the 'Background' name in the Layers field (to leave blank instead of another color like white) if there is like the below:
[image]

- Change the canvas size from Image menu ( Width: 720 pixels to 722 pixels and Height: 1280 pixels to 1282 pixels). Now, should see 1 pixel gap at every side of the splash screen image.
Then you can use C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio\sdk\tools\draw9patch.bat to convert a 9-patch file. For that open your splash screen on draw9patch app. You should define your logo and expandable areas. Notice the black line the following example splash screen. The black line's thickness is just 1 px ;) Left and Top sides black lines define your splash screen's must display area. Exactly as your designed. Right and Bottom lines define the addable and removable area (automatically repeating areas).

**Just do that:**
Zoom your image's top edge on draw9patch application. Click and drag your mouse to draw line. And press shift + click and drag your mouse to erase line.

[image: Sample 9-patch design]

If you develop a cross-platform app (like Cordova/PhoneGap) you can find the following address almost all mabile OS splash screen sizes. Click for [Windows Phone](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/App-Splash-Screen-Sizes#windows-phone), [WebOS](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/App-Splash-Screen-Sizes#webos), [BlackBerry](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/App-Splash-Screen-Sizes#blackberry), [Bada-WAC](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/App-Splash-Screen-Sizes#bada-wac) and [Bada](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/App-Splash-Screen-Sizes#bada) splash screen sizes.

https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/App-Splash-Screen-Sizes

And if you need IOS, Android etc. app icon sizes you can [visit here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/App-Icon-Sizes).

### IOS

```
Format : PNG (recommended)

Dimensions

 - Tablet (iPad)
   - Non-Retina (1x)
     - Portrait: 768x1024px
     - Landscape: 1024x768px
   - Retina (2x)
     - Portrait: 1536x2048px
     - Landscape: 2048x1536px
 - Handheld (iPhone, iPod)
   - Non-Retina (1x)
     - Portrait: 320x480px
     - Landscape: 480x320px
   - Retina (2x)
     - Portrait: 640x960px
     - Landscape: 960x640px
 - iPhone 5 Retina (2x)
   - Portrait: 640x1136px
   - Landscape: 1136x640px
 - iPhone 6 (2x)
   - Portrait: 750x1334px
   - Landscape: 1334x750px
 - iPhone 6 Plus (3x)
   - Portrait: 1242x2208px
   - Landscape: 2208x1242px
```

Answer (score 109):

**For Android Mobile Devices**

LDPI-
icon-36x36, splash-426x320 (now with correct values)

---

MDPI-
icon-48x48, splash-470x320

---

HDPI-
icon 72x72, splash- 640x480

---

XHDPI-
icon-96x96, splash- 960x720

---

XXHDPI-
icon- 144x144

All in pixels.

**For Android Tablet Devices**

```
LDPI:
    Portrait: 200x320px
    Landscape: 320x200px
MDPI:
    Portrait: 320x480px
    Landscape: 480x320px
HDPI:
    Portrait: 480x800px
    Landscape: 800x480px
XHDPI:
    Portrait: 720px1280px
    Landscape: 1280x720px
```

Comment: @Geobits: both are in pixels. That is for different resolutions. I don't see any confusion there. strange!!

Comment: The sizes you give for `ldpi/mdpi/hdpi/xhdpi` correspond with `small/normal/large/xlarge` in dp according to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html). Also, if they *are* pixels sizes, they should be of the scale `0.75/1/1.5/2`. Do you have a source for these sizes that I'm not seeing?

Comment: @NijilNair : how come the resolution of images on tablet is smaller than on mobile phones?! Should it not be the other way around? For example, I am surprised with the "Mobile phone ldpi : 426x320 " and then "Tablet ldpi : 320 x 200"... does not seem logical at all. Thanks for answering!

Comment: @Phalanx : check this link. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html#ConfigurationExamples.

Comment: Are you sure LDPI icon is not 36x36?

Comment: But where is XXHDPI splashscreen?

Answer (score 35):

- LDPI: Portrait: 200 X 320px. Landscape: 320 X 200px.
- MDPI: Portrait: 320 X 480px. Landscape: 480 X 320px.
- HDPI: Portrait: 480 X 800px. Landscape: 800 X 480px.
- XHDPI: Portrait: 720 X 1280px. Landscape: 1280 X 720px.
- XXHDPI: Portrait: 960 X 1600px. Landscape: 1600 X 960px.
- XXXHDPI: Portrait: 1280 X 1920px. Landscape: 1920 X 1280px.

Comment: Everywhere I read xhdpi is just double to mdpi, so according to that xhdpi should be 640 x 960, but you wrote it 720x1280. Can you please explain how it is 720x1280? Which formula you used?

Comment: Isn't xxxhdpi 1440x2560? According to this list, where Google Pixel XL is listed as xxxhdpi https://material.io/resources/devices/

Answer (score 10):

- Xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- List item large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- List item normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- List item small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

Use this to create your images and put them in specific resource folder.

Answer (score 7):

Just use this website: http://ticons.fokkezb.nl :)

It makes it easier for you, and generates the correct sizes directly

Comment: This website appears to be for iOS images, not Android.

Comment: I used it for android, and was quite satisfied with the results ;à

Comment: The website is down now.

Answer (score 2):

xlarge screens  are at least 960dp x 720dp layout-xlarge 10" tablet (720x1280 mdpi, 800x1280 mdpi, etc.)

large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp tweener tablet like the Streak (480x800 mdpi), 7" tablet (600x1024 mdpi)

normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp layout    typical phone screen (480x800 hdpi)

small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp typical phone screen (240x320 ldpi, 320x480 mdpi, etc.)