# Perfect Splash Screen Size for Smart Phone, Tablets in Android

Tags: android, splash-screen

I want Perfect Splash Screen Size for Smart Phones and Tables.
I have Size for Smart Phone but I am being confused after seen another some posts who are showing different sizes.
**For Smart Phone :**

```
drawable-hdpi, drawable-mdpi, drawable-xhdpi, drawable-xxhdpi
```

**For Tablet:**

```
drawable-large, drawable-small, drawable-normal, drawable-xlarge<br><br>
```

Right now, I have sizes as per below :

- xlarge (xhdpi): 640x960
- large (hdpi): 480x800
- medium (mdpi): 320x480
- small (ldpi): 240x320
  From [Supporting Multiple Screens](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)
- xlarge screens are at least 960dp x 720dp
- large screens are at least 640dp x 480dp
- normal screens are at least 470dp x 320dp
- small screens are at least 426dp x 320dp

Please help me regarding this. And also tell me size for Tablet Splash Screen Size.

Comment: Check out this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19875158/android-background-image-size-in-pixel/19875228#19875228

Comment: @Haresh, check comment of that source.

Comment: use those sizes it'll sizes it'll show in full screen

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the question is vaguely worded. What do you mean by splash screen size? Since you will be loading splash for full screen, *what does pixels for screen mean*? I am going on the *assumption* that this was asked for **Image pixels for different Screen sizes** and provide the answer.

I find image size for Perfect Splash screen size to be relative too as it also depends on the method used for the Splash Screen. Since the image you use can be set according to the size of the screen **programmatically** if it is required to fill **exactly** up to some **percent** of the screen without pixels having much of effect in that if you keep adequate pixelled image ([if the splash screen is loaded as an activity for a specified amount of time from your MainAtivity](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5486970/7550472)). Now, if you are following the drawable method for creating splash screen using theme for calling it (like in [Splash Screens the Right Way](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/splash-screens-the-right-way/) article), well then the Pixels of the image really matters as the size of the image will be determined by the different pixels used for images for different screen sizes. The answer to that is provided exactly in the [android splash screen sizes for ldpi,mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi displays](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13487124/7550472) post.

For lazier developers like myself :P, I will provide the values below for minimum screen sizes (all in pixels), which are provided by Google ([the statistics on the relative sizes of devices on Google's dashboard](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html#Screens)).

---

**Android Mobile Devices :**

LDPI- 426x320

MDPI- 470x320

HDPI- 640x480

XHDPI- 960x720

---

**Android Tablet Devices :**

LDPI- 200x320

MDPI- 320x480

HDPI- 480x800

XHDPI- 720px1280px

---

And ofcourse, the use of [9 Patch images](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html#nine-patch) are always recommended for stretchable images.