# Android splash screen size for Nexus 5x (between xxhdpi and xxxhdpi)

Tags: android, cordova, splash-screen, nexus-5

a lot of similar questions have been asked before but I can't find one that answers my question. 
I'm developing an app with cordova/phonegap so I added splash screen images like this ( i only need portrait):

```
    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" density="port-hdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" density="port-ldpi"/>     
    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" density="port-mdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" density="port-xhdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xxhdpi-portrait.png" density="port-xxhdpi"/>
    <splash src="res/screen/android/screen-xxxhdpi-portrait.png" density="port-xxxhdpi"/>
```

In most documentations (i.e. here: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap/wiki/App-Splash-Screen-Sizes) i read that the xxxhdpi size should be 1920x1080px, so i created a splash screen with this size.

I'm testing the app on my Nexus 5x which has the following specs:

```
    screen resolution:  1920 x 1080 px (730 x 410 dp)   density: 420 dpi
```

And it states:

```
    Nexus 5X has a quantized density of 420 dpi, which falls in between the xhdpi and xxhdpi primary density buckets.
```

At this point the splash screen is not displayed correctly; i has a round logo on it and it does not come out round in my app.

What can i do to get it displayed correctly? I could change the screen-xxhdpi-portrait.png to 1080x1920px but I supppose that wil cause problems on other devices with a proper xxhpdi screen.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the proper solution is to create a 9-patch png. I'm looking into that as we speak.

Comment: I recommend checking this out http://stackoverflow.com/a/27125893/3765109